# Python crash course 8-14

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, keyword-argument

```
def make_car(manufacturer, model_name, **car_info):
    car = {"manufacturer": manufacturer.title(), "model name": model_name.title()}

    for keys, values in car_info.items():
        car[keys] = values.title()
        return car


car = make_car("honda", "accord", colour="black", speed=300, year=2015)

print(car)
```

This is my current code. I have a problem that only 1 of the arbitrary keyword arguments show when I run.

```
{'manufacturer': 'Honda', 'model name': 'Accord', 'colour': 'Black'}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Deindent the return statement so it is not inside your for loop.

Comment: I'm the author of Python Crash Course. The solutions to most exercises are [here](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/solutions/solutions/).

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
for keys, values in car_info.items():
    car[keys] = values.title()
    return car
```

you have your return statement inside your for loop, so in the first iteration of your loop, the function will return, and the rest of the loop will not be executed.

Deindent the return statement so it is not inside the loop.

```
for keys, values in car_info.items():
    car[keys] = values.title()
return car
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning inside the loop, also there is another bug, title function is only for strings, it wont work for int datatype.

```
def make_car(manufacturer, model_name, **car_info):
    car = {"manufacturer": manufacturer.title(), "model name": model_name.title()}

    for keys, values in car_info.items():
        car[keys] = values.title() if type(values)==str else values
    return car


car = make_car("honda", "accord", colour="black", speed=300, year=2015)

print(car)
```